# Influence of big values in hidden layers on the output value of the output layer

Tags: neural-networks, sigmoid-curve

In the lab on Tensorflow classification, we are trying to predict wether a coffe is well roasted or badly. A 1 is good roasted and 0 is bad. The architecture is:
[image: Architecture]

Now we try to visualize the trained model. The lab says "The shading shows that each unit is responsible for a different "bad roast" region. unit 0 has larger values when the temperature is too low. unit 1 has larger values when the duration is too short and unit 2 has larger values for bad combinations of time/temp. It is worth noting that the network learned these functions on its own through the process of gradient descent. They are very much the same sort of functions a person might choose to make the same decisions."

The lab created this plot.The Xs correspond to good roasted and the circles are Bad roasted Coffee.The blue hatched regions show the layer ouputted higher activations for the respective unit.
[image: Neural net plot]

But I thought the sigmoid function plots 1 for large values and 0 for small values so shouldn't the layers output small values instead of big values for the bad roasted

Comment: Can you clarify the legend for the plot? From the description, it seems like the x's are negative examples. Also, do the values plotted correspond to the output ${a}^{[2]}$?

Comment: We've left something important out: the weights connecting the output layer to the hidden layer! If these weights are negative, they can make it so that when the output of the *hidden layer units* is high (which is what we're visualizaing), the final output of the neural net itself is actually low (since negative times positive is negative, and goes close to zero after you sigmoid it).